# '502 Bad Gateway nginx' error for browsing Flask app in GCP

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I have this problem on my Google App Engine app. When I run the app with `gcloud app browse` the page gives me the following error message:

> '502 Bad Gateway
>   nginx'

I am using a Flask application.

Here is the code:

```
import os
from flask_uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads, IMAGES, patch_request_class
from uuid import uuid4
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, send_from_directory
import io
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOADED_PHOTOS_DEST'] = os.getcwd()

photos = UploadSet('photos', IMAGES)
configure_uploads(app, photos)
patch_request_class(app)  

APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="json_key.txt"
vision_client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    labels = ''
    file_url1 = ''
    filename = ''
    file_url = ''
    target = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, '/')
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'photo' in request.files:
        filename = photos.save(request.files['photo'])
        file_url = photos.url(filename)
        with io.open(filename, 'rb') as image_file:
            content = image_file.read()
        image = types.Image(content=content)
        response = vision_client.label_detection(image=image)
        labels = response.label_annotations
    return render_template('index.html', thelabels=labels,image_name=file_url)

"""@app.route('/<filename>')
def send_image(filename):
    #return render_template('index.html', filename=filename)
    return send_from_directory("/", filename)"""
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

This is the app.yaml file:

```
runtime: python37
```

And I am not using a requirements.txt file !?

Comment: I'm no expert on Google Cloud App engine, but I would wager that your Flask app is either not running, or it's not configured to map to the correct port, or in your case, I think both.

You say you are not using a requirements.txt file, but you should, since I see you have dependencies that the App engine won't know about.
A simple `pip freeze > requirements.txt` in your project root should do the trick.

Also, I think you should add more config to your yaml file.

[Maybe this article can give you some help](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/quickstart)

Comment: thanks bro all is about the requirement file and app.yaml you should install all the requirement file and packages needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To deploy an App Engine Application you need at least 3 minimum files.

1. App.yaml file with the desired configuration of your setup
2. Main.py with your actual code
3. Requirements.txt in order to import the required libraries

As an alternative you can include the libraries files with your files when you are deploying your App engine Application but this isn't a recommended approach since you will have longer deployment times and longer start up time when you application is scaling.

Here you can see an example of your desired requirements.txt

```
uwsgi==2.0.18
flask==1.1.1
google-cloud==0.34.0
google-cloud-vision==0.39.0
uuid==1.30.0
Flask-Uploads==0.2.1
```

You can also get your required files running the command `pip freeze > requirements.txt` but keep in mind that you should run this command ONLY inside of a test [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) because if you do a pip freeze in your working environment you will get a really long list with many unneeded dependencies that will slow a lot your app deployment